# Using Make to Compile Latex with external packages

Tags: packages, makefile

I am using make to compile my LaTeX files (make is the REQUIRED tool) and am running in to some trouble when trying to build on a 'fresh' computer.

By this I mean the documents contain many `\usepackage`s which are obviously not installed on the 'fresh' machine. Is there some way to include the `.sty` or the packages somehow so that the documents can be made anywhere?

Comment: It is not at all 'obvious' why they are not installed on the new machine. Why aren't they installed?

Comment: If you ship your LaTeX project with the required *.sty on the document root then your problem is solved. Supposing you're not going to ship the essential packages with it, eventually, you're bound to having versioning issues with some packages, I guess.